# In reference to airspace, what does the FAA mean by "within the lateral boundaries of"? Is this construed to also imply a vertical limit?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, ultralight, class-e-airspace, special-vfr

Several FARs use the phrase "within the lateral boundaries of" (x airspace).  What does the FAA interpret this phrase to mean?  Specifically, what is the vertical extent of the airspace encompassed by this phrase?

The common-sense interpretation of this phrase would appear to include any airspace whose latitude-longitude coordinates fall within the boundaries of said airspace, ***regardless of altitude***, from the earth's surface all the way to outer space, or at least to the upper limit of the airspace which the FAA has any regulatory authority over.

Otherwise, it would seem to serve just as well to dispense with the "within the lateral boundaries" phrase and simply say "within" (x airspace).

Is there any evidence that the FAA interprets "within the lateral boundaries of" differently than the meaning noted above?

The answer to this question affects the interpretations of [certain FARs](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74738/what-indications-has-the-faa-given-that-phrases-like-surface-area-of-class-e-ai), describing, among other things, [airspace where ADS-B-out is required](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74808/is-ads-b-required-for-flight-under-class-b-airspace-but-outside-the-mode-c-veil/74856#74856), [airspace where 3 miles visibility is required to enter a traffic pattern under Visual Flight Rules with no special VFR clearance](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.155), [airspace within which aerobatic flight is prohibited](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.303), [airspace where prior authorization is required to operate unmanned free balloons](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/101.33), and [airspace in which an ultralight aircraft may not be flown without prior authorization from ATC](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74384/at-what-altitude-if-any-may-an-ultralight-overfly-the-gallup-airport-kgup-wi).

Comment: I believe the upper limit of the FAA's regulatory authority is FL600, not "all the way to outer space"

Comment: @abelenky-- noted-- question modified.

Comment: Pertains to several answers to this question-- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74808/is-ads-b-required-for-flight-under-class-b-airspace-but-outside-the-mode-c-veil

Comment: @abelenky Class A ends at FL600; above that is class E up to the limits of national airspace, which is currently undefined. Various treaties set it no higher than the Karman Line.

Comment: A big part of me is very reluctant to stir the pot, but recent closure of another question has put a burr under my saddle.  I question the phrase “…of the surface area of Class E airspace designated for an airport”.  This would seem to indicate a vertical limit of some sort, NOT a phrase that uses "lateral".  What is the definition of this term?

Comment: @MichaelHall --ASE moderators are very strongly discouraging me from using comments for discussion so I will answer in this chat room -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142300/discussion-on-question-by-thatguyrj-what-are-lateral-boundaries

Answer (score 1):

The FAA normally interprets the phrase "within the lateral boundaries of" (x airspace) to mean any airspace whose lat-lon coordinates fall within said boundaries, ***regardless of altitude***, from the earth's surface all the way to outer space, or at least to the upper limits of the airspace which the FAA has any regulatory authority over.

Pilots would be wise to follow this common-sense understanding of the meaning of "within the lateral boundaries of".

However, the FAA is not a monolithic entity, nor is it immune to making the occasional blunder.  On a few occasions, some subset of the FAA has adopted a very different understanding of the meaning of "within the lateral boundaries of".

For example, in the text of a spectacularly misguided Final Rule published on page 51966 of the [October 5, 1993 edition of the Federal Register](https://cdn.loc.gov/service/ll/fedreg/fr058/fr058191/fr058191.pdf), the FAA implied that the phrase "within the lateral boundaries of the surface areas of ... Class E airspace designated for an airport" would not encompass any Class E airspace higher than the floor of the 700' or 1200' AGL "transition area" that invariably overlies a Class-E-to-surface airspace.

To correct this imaginary problem, the FAA changed the wording of [FAR 91.157](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.157) from the existing wording

> 91.157 Special VFR weather minimums Except as provided in appendix D, section 3 of this part, the following special weather minimums and
>   requirements apply to operations conducted to or from an airport in
>   controlled airspace:  (a) Operations may be conducted only under an
>   ATC clearance-- (1) Within the lateral boundaries of the surface areas
>   of Class B, Class C, Class D, or Class E airspace designated for an
>   airport; and ...

To the new wording

> 91.157  Special VFR weather minimums ( a ) Except as provided in appendix D,
>   section 3, of this part, special VFR operations may be conducted under
>   the weather minimums and requirements of this section, instead of
>   those contained in 91.155, below 10,000' feet MSL within the airspace
>   contained by the upward extension of the lateral boundaries of the
>   controlled airspace designated to the surface for an airport. (b) 
>   Special VFR operations may only be conducted--(1) With an ATC
>   clearance...

However, the FAA failed to also change the similar wording of FARs [45.22(a)(3)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/45.22), [91.155(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.155), [91.303(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.303), [91.309(a)(4)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.309), [93.152](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/93.152), [101.33(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/101.33), [103.17](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/103.17), [107.41](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/107.41), [135.205(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/135.205), and [137.43(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/137.43), thus implying that none of these FARs should be understood to apply to any Class E airspace above 700' AGL in most cases, or above 1200' AGL in the remaining cases.

This blunder has never been officially corrected-- the text published in the October 5, 1993 edition of the Federal Register has never been officially retracted.

Comment: Also, I have links to discussion forums where pilots report being given a similar answer-- that the phrase doesn't encompass any airspace above the base of the overlying E5 transition layer at 700' or 1200' AGL-- when they queried FAA officials about the meaning of FAR 103.17.  Obviously not the mainstream interpretation-- otherwise most of the FARs listed above would make no sense at all-- consider especially 107.41--

Comment: future edit - last sentence of first paragraph could be changed to end "or above 1200 feet in most  remaining cases."

Comment: This answer would be improved by giving specific examples to support the first paragraph; some may be found in letters of interpretation.

Comment: This answer could be improved by phrasing third paragraph in a way that uses a word stronger than "implied" or else gives the full text to clearly show that this is clearly what they meant.

Comment: This answer would be improved by giving at least one other example, to support the use of the phrase ". On a few occasions".  These answers could be simply cases where FSDO staffers presented such interpretations.

Comment: Possible future edit-- change "imaginary" to "perceived"

Comment: Future edit-- also add portion clarifying that "within the lateral boundaries of the surface area" only pertains to portions of airspace that actually contact the surface.

Comment: Possible future edit-- address the possible argument that if "surface area" is construed to mean just the footprint on the surface rather than an actual chunk of airspace, then it may be difficult to simply dispense with the "within the lateral boundaries" phrase, even the intention is not for the airspace to extend upward indefinitely.  In fact, the FAA clearly does usually construe "surface area" to mean an actual volume of airspace-- support with examples in answer.

Comment: Future edit: re: "thus implying that none of these FARs should be understood to apply to any Class E airspace above 700' AGL in most cases, or above 1200' AGL in the remaining cases." -- change to *and thus implying that we are free to let unmanned free balloons go floating through the surface footprint of Class-E-to-Surface airspace directly over airports, as long as we stay above 1200' AFL, in nearly all (or all) cases.*"

Comment: Here is the clearest evidence that can be found in the FARs that the FAA considers the airspace described as "within the lateral boundaries" of a given airspace to *extend upwards indefinitely, beyond the actual ceiling of that particular airspace* -- see chat posts https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62964015#62964015 through https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62964146#62964146.  The current answer would be improved by adding this content.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65930/far-91-215-b3ii-transponders-significance-of-below-the-altitude-of-the

Comment: An interesting point is that in some of the rule-making documents leading up to the September 1993 "alphabet" airspace re-designation, the FAA proposed allowing ultralights to operate in (or within the lateral boundaries of) the surface-level Class E airspace designated for airports *so long as these operations were conducted above a certain altitude* which I recall was something like 4000 or 5000' AGL-- which was also the standard ceiling that was being proposed at the time for Class D airspace-- the question or answer might benefit from a more thorough note on this fact.

Comment: The above comments are intended as suggestions as to how this answer could be edited for improvement; not yet ready to actually post an edited version--